# PHP - Write string in a certain position of a file

Tags: php

I have the following string in a text file:

```
<!-- 
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Individuals
//
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 -->
```

I need to write text **two lines below** the above part. There are many other sections like the one above, but each one doesn't repeat, so I know there is only one "Individuals".

I need to overwrite the file, so how can I set the position of my output to there?

Comment: are those section names unique?

Comment: @timus2001 Yes, they are.

Comment: u can string replace [// Individuals] with [//Individual /n/n your_text] .. isnt that? or i havent understood ur question

Comment: @timus2001 Yes, this would be a solution. I was thinking about cursors and more file handling, but your suggestion seems OK to me.

Comment: Why not save yourself the hassle and change the marker into something that is just 1 line ?! EG `<!-- // Individuals -->`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two approaches:

1. Read the file line by line. Check each line if it matches to certain conditions. If yes, insert lines.
2. Read the full file, replace the text wanted and write the full file.

As long as your traffic is not too high, method 2 will be simpler. In order to replace the full block, I suggest this regex:

```
/(<!--[\s\r\n/]*Individuals[\s/]*)[^\s/]*([\s/]*-->)/
```

It matches the full block containing "Individuals" followed by some content on the new line. The block before the separate content is being caught by parenthesis, in order to do a replace:

```
$content = file_get_contents('myfile.txt');
$newContent = preg_replace("@(<!--[\s\r\n/]*Individuals[\s/]*)[^\s/]*([\s/]*-->)@", "$1$myNames$2", $content);    
file_put_contents('myfile.txt', $newContent);
```

The `preg_replace` concatenates the first part of the block, some slashes and "Individuals", together with `$myNames`, and together with the closing part of the block to a new block.

I have not tested this finally in the shell, so I apologize for a possible typo. But I'm sure this will work out.

Comment: Thanks, Peter. But your regex does not support the whole block of the question. This is what I'm trying to fix.

Comment: I've edited it so that it replaces the full block :-)